# Bootstrap responsive iframe not being resized and embed classes not showing up

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

my responsive-item is not working. I already tried looking around for an answer but nothing has worked so far.
Maybe it has something to do with that I want my tow to be 100% in height (100% viewport height - my section is set to 100vh)
But i'm not sure

```
 <section class="container">

        <div class="row h-100">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div>
                    <div class="embed-responsive">
                        <iframe
                            width="100%"
                            class="embed-responsive-item"
                            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0"
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6"></div>

        </div>

  </section>
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I noticed that at page launch i don't even have the needed embed classes at my elements - everything else from bootstrap is working fine
I have included:

```
    <link
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD"
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

and

```
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY
        0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

so the main problem is that I don't actually have those classes

Comment: You're loading two different versions of Bootstrap, including an unstable alpha version and a very old version 4.0. Neither are advisable.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 does not use embed classes anymore - its ratio
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/

Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
                        <iframe
                            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0"
                            title="YouTube video"
                            allowfullscreen> </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div
```

Comment: You should link to the current documentation, not a very old 5.0.